# Understanding repr( ) function in Python

Tags: python, repr

`repr()`: evaluatable string representation of an object (can "eval()"
it, meaning it is a string representation that evaluates to a Python
object)

In other words:

```
>>> x = 'foo'
>>> repr(x)
"'foo'"
```

Questions:

1. Why do I get the double quotes  when I do `repr(x)`? (I don't get them
   when I do `str(x)`)
2. Why do I get `'foo'` when I do `eval("'foo'")` and not x which is the
   object?

Answer (score 173, accepted):

```
>>> x = 'foo'
>>> x
'foo'
```

So the name `x` is attached to `'foo'` string. When you call for example `repr(x)` the interpreter puts `'foo'` instead of `x` and then calls `repr('foo')`.

```
>>> repr(x)
"'foo'"
>>> x.__repr__()
"'foo'"
```

`repr` actually calls a magic method `__repr__` of `x`, which gives the **string** containing the representation of the value `'foo'` assigned to `x`. So it returns `'foo'` inside the string `""` resulting in `"'foo'"`. The idea of `repr` is to give a string which contains a series of symbols which we can type in the interpreter and get the same value which was sent as an argument to `repr`.

```
>>> eval("'foo'")
'foo'
```

When we call `eval("'foo'")`, it's the same as we type `'foo'` in the interpreter. It's as we directly type the contents of the outer string `""` in the interpreter.

```
>>> eval('foo')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    eval('foo')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

If we call `eval('foo')`, it's the same as we type `foo` in the interpreter. But there is no `foo` variable available and an exception is raised.

```
>>> str(x)
'foo'
>>> x.__str__()
'foo'
>>>
```

`str` is just the string representation of the object (remember, `x` variable refers to `'foo'`), so this function returns string.

```
>>> str(5)
'5'
```

String representation of integer `5` is `'5'`.

```
>>> str('foo')
'foo'
```

And string representation of string `'foo'` is the same string `'foo'`.

Comment: Can you also let us know some use cases when one should use repr function.
I am unable to comprehend that

Answer (score 14):

The feedback you get on the interactive interpreter uses `repr` too. When you type in an expression (let it be `expr`), the interpreter basically does `result = expr; if result is not None: print repr(result)`. So the second line in your example *is* formatting the string `foo` into the representation you want (`'foo'`). And then the interpreter creates the `repr`esentation of *that*, leaving you with double quotes.

> Why when I combine %r with double-quote and single quote escapes and print them out, it prints it the way I'd write it in my .py file but not the way I'd like to see it?

I'm not sure what you're asking here. The text `single ' and double " quotes`, when run through `repr`, includes escapes for one kind of quote. Of course it does, otherwise it wouldn't be a valid string literal by Python rules. That's precisely what you asked for by calling `repr`.

Also note that the `eval(repr(x)) == x` analogy isn't meant literal. It's an approximation and holds true for most (all?) built-in types, but the main thing is that you get a fairly good idea of the type and logical "value" from looking the the `repr` output.

Comment: Originally, it actually _was_ meant to be literal: every value's `repr` should either be something that can be passed to `eval` (or copied and pasted into your source code) to produce an equal value, or something that will raise a SyntaxError when you try that (usually the `<…>` style produced by `object.__repr__`). That was gradually toned down over the years, and by 2.7 and 3.x it's just true "for many types", and there are exceptions even in the stdlib (e.g,, a `namedtuple` type created as a local will give you a `repr` you can't `eval`), but it was the original idea.

Answer (score 9):

`str()` is used for creating output for end user while `repr()` is used for debugging during development. And it's an official representation of the object.

Example:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> today = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> str(today)
'2018-04-08 18:00:15.178404'
>>> repr(today)
'datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 8, 18, 3, 21, 167886)'
```

From output we see that `repr()` shows the official representation of date object.

Answer (score 4):

1) The result of `repr('foo')` is the *string* `'foo'`. In your Python shell, the result of the expression is expressed as a representation too, so you're essentially seeing `repr(repr('foo'))`.

2) `eval` calculates the result of an expression. The result is always a *value* (such as a number, a string, or an object). Multiple variables can refer to the same value, as in:

```
x = 'foo'
y = x
```

x and y now refer to the same value.

3) I have no idea what you meant here. Can you post an example, and what you'd like to see?

Answer (score 3):

When you say

```
foo = 'bar'
baz(foo)
```

you are not passing `foo` to the `baz` function.  `foo` is just a name used to represent a value, in this case `'bar'`, and that value is passed to the `baz` function.