# Why are some Python strings are printed with quotes and some are printed without quotes?

Tags: python, string, representation

I have a problem with string representations. I am trying to print my object and I sometimes get single quotes in the output. Please help me to understand why it happens and how can I print out the object without quotes.

Here is my code:

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, value, *children):
        self.value = value
        self.children = list(children)
        self.marker = ""

    def __repr__(self):
        if len(self.children) == 0:
            return '%s' %self.value
        else:
            childrenStr = ' '.join(map(repr, self.children))
            return '(%s %s)' % (self.value, childrenStr)
```

Here is what I do:

```
from Tree import Tree
t = Tree('X', Tree('Y','y'), Tree('Z', 'z'))
print t
```

Here is what I get:

```
(X (Y 'y') (Z 'z'))
```

Here is what I want to get:

```
(X (Y y) (Z z))
```

Why do the quotes appear around the values of terminal nodes, but not around the values of non-terminals?

Comment: OK, I found the explanation why repr(x) produces strings in quotes [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784148/understanding-repr-function-in-python)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`repr` on a string gives quotes while `str` does not.  e.g.:

```
>>> s = 'foo'
>>> print str(s)
foo
>>> print repr(s)
'foo'
```

Try:

```
def __repr__(self):
    if len(self.children) == 0:
        return '%s' %self.value
    else:
        childrenStr = ' '.join(map(str, self.children))  #str, not repr!
        return '(%s %s)' % (self.value, childrenStr)
```

instead.