# extract one element from the list with quotation mark

Tags: python, list, quotation-marks

I would like to extract one element from list in python.

For example:

```
a = [0,1,2,3]
b = ['0','1','2','3']
a1 = a[0]
b1 = b[0]
print(a1)
print(b1)
```

As expected, the code print 0 for both a1 and b1.

However I would like to get '0' for both a1 and b1 with single quotation mark instead of 0.

Any idea or help would be really appreciate.

Thank you,

Issac

Comment: Do you want just to print it, or do you need the three-characters-long string '0' for further processing?

Comment: This is not how values and types work. the output of `print(0)` and `print('0')` will be the same in almost any language, but that's also mostly completely irrelevant. if you want to print a single quote, `print("'")` a single quote.

Comment: @GPhilo: I need the three-characters-ling string '0'. Thank you,

Comment: @Isaac you define a string `my_string = "'{}'".format(a1)`. `my_string` will contain `'0'` and have length 3.

Comment: @GPhilo: Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Quotation marks are not parts of a value - they are only for distinguish e. g. *the number* `1` from *the string* with the only *symbol* `1`.

The `print()` function *don't print quotation marks even around strings* (unlike  an interactive session when you give as input *only a variable name or an expression*).

So you have manually put them into the `print()` function, e. g.

```
print("'" + str(a1) + "'")
print("'" + b1 + "'")
```

or

```
print("'{}'".format(a1))
print("'{}'".format(b1))
```

or - in Python 3.6+ -

```
print(f"'{a1}'")
print(f"'{b1}'")
```

Comment: the `print()` function outputs only the value to the screen. the quotes are not part of the (string) value '1'.

Comment: @hop I don't understand - how it is related to my answer?

Comment: it further clarifies your answer. i didn't want to be rude and edit your answer.

Comment: @hop - Oh, I understood your comment now - you are right and I am going to put it in my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Normally, Python will print a string without quotes. That's standard in almost all programming languages.

However, Python *does* let you print a string with the quotes, you just need to tell it to print the *representation* of the string. One way to do that is with the `!r` formatting directive.

The items in `a` are integers, if you want them printed as strings you need to convert them to strings.

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
b = ['0','1','2','3']
a1 = a[0]
b1 = b[0]

print('{!r}'.format(str(a1)))
print('{!r}'.format(b1))
```

**output**

```
'0'
'0'
```

---

You can read about the representation of a string in [the official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting).

There are other ways to see the representation of a string. For example, you can call the built-in [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) function:

```
print(repr(b1))
```

Bear in mind that if a string already contains single-quote chars then its representation will be enclosed in double-quotes:

```
s = "A 'test' string"
print(repr(s))
```

**output**

```
"A 'test' string"
```

And if the string contains a mixture of quotes then the representation will revert to using single quotes, and using backslash escapes to denote single quotes:

```
s = "A 'test' \"string\""
print(repr(s))
```

**output**

```
'A \'test\' "string"'
```

So if for some reason you don't want that behaviour, then you will need to print the quote marks explicitly:

```
s = "A 'test' string"
print("'{}'".format(s))
```

**output**

```
'A 'test' string'
```

Comment: you should not rely on the behaviour of `repr()` in this case. just print the quotes explicitely.

Comment: @hop What do you mean, exactly? I think my answer covers most of the common options.

Comment: my comment was from befor the edit. the second half of you answer shows why it is a bad idea to rely on `repr()`.

Answer (score 0):

well,

```
>>> print(repr(str(a1)))
'0'
>>> print(repr(str(b1)))
'0'
```

will do, but as commented by others I am unsure about your intentions.

Answer (score 0):

I searched online and found [Why are some Python strings are printed with quotes and some are printed without quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17171889/why-are-some-python-strings-are-printed-with-quotes-and-some-are-printed-without)

I think if you print as follows, it will work as you wish:

```
print(repr(a1))
print(repr(b1))
```