# extract the integer and unicodes from each item in the list

Tags: python, list, unicode

I am doing my project in linguistics (Language is Malayalam).

My list is

```
x= [u'1\u0d30\u0d3e\u0d2e\u0d28\u0d4d\u200d', u'5\u0d05\u0d35\u0d28\u0d4d\u200d']
```

I want to extract the integer and unicodes from each item in the list.

The expected output is

```
1 \u0d30\u0d3e\u0d2e\u0d28\u0d4d\u200  
5 \u0d05\u0d35\u0d28\u0d4d\u200d
```

First i tried to convert the first item x[0] into ascii

```
print unicodedata.normalize('NFKD',x[0]).encode('ascii','ignore')
```

the output is 1 .

I think this output is generated because the unicode in list is for malayalam.

Then i tried to find the first index of "\u" like

```
x[0].index("\u")
```

Error occurred by doing this.

Comment: Look here for more information on the python `repr` function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784148/understanding-repr-function-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character sequences `\uXXXX` represent a single unicode character, not a sequence of characters in the string.

You can get the expected output as follows:

```
for i in x:
    print int(i[0]), repr(i[1:])[2:-1]
```

(assuming the integer has only one digit)

For the more general case, one solution is to extract the integer using a regular expression:

```
import re
for i in x:
    s = re.match('([0-9]+)', i).group(1)
    print int(s), repr(i[len(s):])[2:-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> x= [u'1\u0d30\u0d3e\u0d2e\u0d28\u0d4d\u200d', u'5\u0d05\u0d35\u0d28\u0d4d\u200d']  
>>> res = [ (i[:1], i[1:]) for i in x ]
>>> res
[(u'1', u'\u0d30\u0d3e\u0d2e\u0d28\u0d4d\u200d'), (u'5', u'\u0d05\u0d35\u0d28\u0d4d\u200d')]

>>> for i in res:
...     print i[0], repr(i[1])
... 
1 u'\u0d30\u0d3e\u0d2e\u0d28\u0d4d\u200d'
5 u'\u0d05\u0d35\u0d28\u0d4d\u200d'
```

Comment: The representation of `res` in the interpreter is the output OP wants, but it's not what you get when you `print` it. You need to use the `repr` function to obtain the object representation.

Comment: Yes i get it, if we use 'print' it prints the actual unicode object. So for that we need to use repr function.
Thanks :)