# Python - Description of repr()

Tags: python, python-3.x, repr

I've read the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=repr#object.__repr__) on `repr()` but I have a feeling that it may be more useful than the docs are giving it credit for.  If my speculative feeling is correct, is someone able to provide instances with which `repr()` comes into its own.

Comment: Did you check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7784214/1595865)?

Comment: Yeh I read this page, at my current level of understanding I can't seem to recognise a use for repr(), is there an example that can be supplied which may flick the switch on.

Comment: The main use for `repr()` for me is to show debug output of complex data structures.  While `str()` should give a representation which is less technical (e. g. `Martin Shultz, developer`), the `repr()` should give a version which can be read as Python source and ideally will create that object anew (e. g. `Person('Martin', 'Shultz', 'developer')`), although this often is not possible for complex objects, of course.