# How to display a class like a called variable?

Tags: python, class, magic-methods

Say I declare:

> x = 5

In a terminal if I type x, I get its value displayed.

> 5

I'd like to do this for a class object as well, which I imagine would be something like this?

```
class foo():
    def __init__(self)
        self.x = "derp"
    def __info__(self)
        return(self.x)  #Or print(self.x)??? I don't know.
```

It's simple, but possibly too simple for anyone to have needed it. I've searched all around about magic methods (an apparently still poorly documented feature), but the best I've found is **str**, **repr**, and **call**.

Does anyone know of such an elusive method?
Thanks!!

Edit: durrr, its **repr** after all....

Comment: It should be `repr`. Did you try it?

Comment: There is also the (somewhat unused) backtick shorthand for `__repr__` in Python 2: Surround something in backticks and it calls repr on that thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `__repr__()`:

```
>>> class Foo():
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return "I'm Foo"
... 
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo
I'm Foo
```

Also see:

- [Representing your Classes](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html#representations) from "A Guide to Python's Magic Methods"
- [Difference between __str__ and __repr__ in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python)
- [Understanding repr( ) function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784148/understanding-repr-function-in-python)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Whoa, okay so it turns out I'd had __repr__ written into my code incorrectly, so I thought it did something else. Second look fixed it. thanks!