# How to print a string value of a dicionary without the quotes?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
In [4]: {'a': "hello"}['a']
Out[4]: 'hello'
```

I want the output to instead be:

```
Out[4]: hello
```

What's the most elegant way to achieve this?

I am also using repr().rjust() later on to print a list of dictionaries into a neatly formatted table, and I notice the repr function also adds quotes which is annoying:

```
def print_dictionary(d): print repr(d['a']).rjust(10)
print_dictionary({'a':'hello'})
```

yields:

```
   'hello'
```

when I want:

```
     hello
```

Comment: `print({'a': "hello"}['a'])`, why are you using repr if you don't want quotes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784148/understanding-repr-function-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just drop the `repr`:

```
def print_dictionary(d): print (d['a']).rjust(10)
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why I was using repr. I just copied it from an example that had it but now I realize it is unnecessary.