# Accessing child widgets of a window by their names?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, children

Is there any way in Python/tkinter to access child elements referring by their variable names, but from an other function?

For example in VBA, it is possible to directly refer to an element of an other window by its name.
For example if I have two windows, `UserForm1` and `UserForm2` I can change the text value of `Label1` of `UserForm2` by clicking a button on `UserForm1`.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  UserForm2.Label1.Caption = "Changed"
End Sub
```

In tkinter I have found the `winfo_children()` to access child elements. Is there any way to access them by their names?

See my sample code below:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def new(parent_window):
    """"""
    parent_window.withdraw()
    global main_window
    global new_window
    new_window = tkinter.Tk()
    new_window.title("My App - New")

    label1 = tkinter.Label(new_window, text="NEW")
    label1.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3,pady=10,padx=10, sticky="nsw")

    b1 = tkinter.Button(new_window, text="Change It", command=lambda: showdashboard(new_window))
    b1.grid(row=4,column=1,padx=20,pady=10,sticky="nwse")

    b2 = tkinter.Button(new_window, text="Quit", command=lambda: quit())
    b2.grid(row=5,column=1,padx=20,pady=10,sticky="nwse")

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def dashboard(parent_window):
    """"""
    parent_window.withdraw()
    global main_window
    global dashboard_window
    dashboard_window = tkinter.Tk()
    dashboard_window.title("My App - Dashboard")

    label1 = tkinter.Label(dashboard_window, text="Dashboard")
    label1.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3,pady=10,padx=10, sticky="nsw")

    b1 = tkinter.Button(dashboard_window, text="New", command=lambda: new(dashboard_window))
    b1.grid(row=4,column=1,padx=20,pady=10,sticky="nwse")

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def showdashboard(parent_window):
    """"""
    parent_window.withdraw()
    dashboard_window.update()
    dashboard_window.deiconify()
    #This way it works <<<<<<<<<<<<<<------!!!!!!!
    byID=dashboard_window.winfo_children()
    byID[0].config(text="change the value")
    #But I am looking for somethin like this <<<<<<<<<<<<<<------????
    dashboard_window.label1.config(text="changed the value")

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
main_window=tkinter.Tk()
main_window.title("MyApp")

label = tkinter.Label(main_window, text="My App")
label.grid(row=0,column=0,pady=10,padx=10,sticky="nwse")

b1 = tkinter.Button(main_window, text="Dashboard", command=lambda:dashboard(main_window))
b1.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=20,pady=10,sticky="nwse")

main_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _names_? Actual variable reference of the children?

Comment: There's a big misconception here: Tkinter elements don't actually _have_ names. Just because you stored the element in a variable at some point doesn't mean that the variable's name is now somehow attached to the element itself.

Comment: Sorry for my inaccuracy. I have just updated my original question with a sample code and a more precise question:"access child elements referring by their variable names, but from an other function". Is it more clear now, what I am looking for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter: access specifc widgets created with for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71902896/tkinter-access-specifc-widgets-created-with-for-loop)

Answer (score 1):

`winfo_children()` returns an instance of the `class` associated with the type of widget along with the name that tkinter assigned to the actual tk object.

This means that yes, we can refer to the name of widget, although I'm not sure what advantage this would really give you other than not needing to assign the label to a variable.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

Label(root, text="Label1").pack()
label2 = Label(root, name="name", text="Label2")

label2.pack()

print(root.winfo_children())
print(root.nametowidget('.!label'))
print(str(label2))

Button(root, text="Delete label2", command=lambda: root.nametowidget(".name").destroy()).pack()
```

The above will result in two `Label` widgets and a `Button` widget appearing in the window. The first `Label` is not stored in a variable and yet we can quite happily call it inside the print statement. The second is stored in a variable but you can see that in the `command` of the `Button` we don't refer to the variable but the name attribute of the `Label`.

[Bryan Oakley has a fantastic answer here explaining this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30005893/4528269)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by *names* in:

> *"Is there any way in Python/tkinter to access child elements referring by their names?"*

You can access widgets simply by their object references:

```
# Procedural
import tkinter as tk


def change():
    object_reference['text'] = "Changed!"

root = tk.Tk()
object_reference = tk.Label(root, text="This is a label for root-window")
object_reference.pack()

another_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
btn_in_other_window = tk.Button(another_window, text="Change")
btn_in_other_window['command'] = change
btn_in_other_window.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

or if they were to be defined with more of an object-oriented approach, you can make use of the `.`(dot) notation:

```
#oop
import tkinter as tk


class App1(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__()

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="This is App1's label")
        self.label.pack()


class App2(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="This is a App2's button")
        self.button.pack()


def change(label):
    label['text'] = "Changed!"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()

    app1 = App1(root)
    app2 = App2(root)
    app2.button['command'] = lambda label=app1.label: change(label)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's not object references but rather the variables that the object references are stored in. Also, both of these examples are showing the same thing, referring to variables. Just one is in OOP and one is not.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, it is possible to get a list of the children widgets of the element window with:

```
root.update()
lista = list(root.children.values())
```

Then it is possible to refer to the list elements and do whatever with the widget itself. For example to get the width of the first widget do `print(lista[0].winfo_width())`.

**Warning:** I am not sure that the list contains the elements in the same order that the widgets appear in the script, although for me it worked in this order. Hopping someone will write in the comments.

Comment: **_"tkinter elements do not have names."** This statement is completely false. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/71906287/16187613

Comment: Ethan has already answered using the same approch.