# working of \n in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am currently taking a course in python. When talking about escape sequences they told about `"\n"` is used for printing strings in new line. But when it is used in the following ways why I am getting a different output

```
>>> st = "Hello\nWorld"
>>> st
'Hello\nWorld'
```

But if I do

```
>>> print st
Hello
World
```

Comment: Also see [Difference between `__str__` and `__repr__` in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1436703/4014959)

Comment: Another related link: [Understanding repr( ) function in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7784148/4014959)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two functions that give an object's string representation, `repr()` and `str()`. The former is designed to convert the object to as-code string, while the latter gives user-friendly string.

When you input the variable name in the command line, `repr()` is used, and `\n` character is shown as `\n` (as-code). When you use `print`, `str()` is used, and `\n` is shown as a new line (user-friendly).

---

By the way, `str` is a bad name for a variable, as it's the same as the built-in.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
st
```

It is somewhat similar to

```
"\n"
```

where you expect the string `\n` in return, and not a new line.

In both cases, the print function is not called which can actually process what `\n` really means. That's why `print 'Hello\nWorld'` gives different output than

```
>>> 'Hello\nWorld'
```