# How to properly get all the data in excel from dataframe in google colab

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

I have a dataframe in google colab when I print the dataframe this is the output I get:

```
                                  0
0                    Aaron Burciaga
1                             \nECS
2    \nVP Artificial Intelligence\n
3               Chanchal Chatterjee
4                    \nGoogle, Inc.
..                              ...
247                       \nI2chain
248                     \nFounder\n
249            Chandrashekar Bhat M
250                       \nTrashin
251                         \nCEO\n
```

However when I export the dataframe in excel I get the below output
[image]

Can someone help me figure out how to properly export the data.

My code:

```
  tmpList = []
  speaker_name = soup.find_all('h4', class_ = 'clearfix Roboto-Medium font15 sbl-t t-b-   m0 dks-t l-h20' )  
  for name in speaker_name:
  print(name.text)
  tmpList.append(name.text)

  df1 = pd.DataFrame(tmpList)
  df1
  print(df1)
  df1.to_csv('sample.csv')
  files.download("sample.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the [`\n`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31489377/working-of-n-in-python) at the beginning (of some) of your values. Just [strip](https://www.w3resource.com/pandas/series/series-str-strip.php) them.<sup>In case you haven't figured it out, the values are present in each cell, but not at the first (visible) line.</sup>

So what about replacing `df1 = pd.DataFrame(tmpList)` by

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(tmpList).applymap(str.strip)
```

?