# Adding a new line character to a variable in python

Tags: python

I have the below function to get the below output

```
22
4444
666666
```

Instead i'm getting

```
'22\n4444\n666666\n88888888\n'
```

Any ideas where im going wrong?

```
def EvenLadder(n):
    ...:     solution = ''
    ...:     if n <= 1:
    ...:         return solution
    ...:     elif n%2 ==0:
    ...:         for i in range(2,n+1,2):
    ...:             solution += (str(i)*i)+"\n"
    ...:     else:
    ...:         n = n - 1
    ...:         for i in range(2,n+1,2):    
    ...:             solution += (str(i)*i)+"\n"
    ...:     return solution
```

Comment: Try doing `print(EvenLadder(n))` . You are just seeing the output of `repr()` , when you call the function without printing or storing the result in a variable . Give some value for `n` , obviously.

Comment: Your code works fine for me, The result is the same as you wished.

Comment: print EvenLadder(6).__repr__() - '22\n4444\n666666\n';                                   print EvenLadder(6) - 22
4444
666666

Comment: yea .. print works .. thanks :)

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/1436703/4014959 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/7784148/4014959

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'22\n4444\n666666\n88888888\n'` is the correct string representation of the expected result. In order to actually process the newline characters you need to print it:

```
print EvenLadder(6)
```