# Python - What happens when I write statements in the interpreter without 'print'?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I just started learning python 2.7.11 from the docs.
I was doing the examples which were given in there, but got confused when `print` and `r` were introduced. I got confused about the how backslashes are being displayed as output. This is related to character escaping but till now I just used `\b` for backspace, `\n` for new line, `\\` for a backslash

This is what I am talking about:

[image]

There are four different cases:

1. using neither `print` nor `r`
2. using `print` but not `r`
3. using `r` but not `print`
4. using both `print` and `r`

and all of them give different outputs. I can't get my head around what's actually happening in all the four cases.

Comment: You are seeing the difference between repr and str when you don't print and print respectively http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784148/understanding-repr-function-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no connection between the two, necessarily. `r` introduces a raw string literal, which doesn't parse escape codes, which means that a `\` between the quotes will be an actual `\` character in the string data.

`print` will print out the actual string, while just typing a string literal at the `>>>` prompt will cause Python to implicitly print the value of the string, but it will be printed as a string literal (with special characters escaped), so you could take it, paste it back into `>>>` and get the same string.

Edit: [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) was mentioned in some of the comments. Basically, it's meant to return a representation of an object that can be parsed back into an equivalent object, whereas `str()` is aimed more towards a human-readable description. For built-in objects, both are predefined as appropriate, while for user objects, you can define them by defining the special methods `__repr__()` and `__str__()`.

`>>> obj` will print out `repr(obj)`, while `print obj` will print the value of `str(obj)`.

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __str__(self):
...             return "str of Foo"
...     def __repr__(self):
...             return "Foo()"
...
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f
Foo()
>>> print f
str of Foo
>>> eval(repr(f))
Foo()
```

Also, regarding the `\`es, it would also be worth noting that Python will ignore escape sequences it doesn't know:

```
>>> [c for c in '\w']
['\\', 'w']
>>> [c for c in '\n']
['\n']
```

`\n` becomes a newline character, while `\w` remains a backslash followed by a `w`.

For example, in `'hello\\\world'`, the first `\` escapes the second one, and the third one is left alone because it's followed by a `w`.

Comment: I'd suggest that to be complete this answer needs to reference `repr()`.

Comment: It uses the repr output unless you print

Comment: that cleared the first case... `print` prints the actual string, is that why \ stays a \ and \\ turns into \ ?

Comment: @vicky96 it is the difference between `__str__` and `__repr__` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python#

Comment: okay almost all of my doubts are cleared except for the 3rd case i.e. using only `r`... why are the number of backslashes doubled?

Comment: @vicky96, because you have to use a backslash to escape a backslash if you want to actually print a backslash in your string