# Multiple .replace() ?? and understanding the "u" which gets added to record from excel file (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need some help with this code:

```
import pyexcel as pe
import pyexcel.ext.xls
import pyexcel.ext.xlsx

def randStrings(excelFile1,excelFile2):
    getNameList = pe.get_sheet(file_name=excelFile1)
    randName = sum([i for i in getNameList],[])
    getCompanyList = pe.get_sheet(file_name=excelFile2)
    randCompany = sum([i for i in getCompanyList],[])
    randStrings.name = random.choice(randName)
    randStrings.combinedString = random.choice(randName) + "@" + random.choice(randCompany).lower().replace(" ","").replace("'","").replace("/","").replace(".","").replace(",","") +".com"
    return randStrings.name, randStrings.combinedString

randStrings("names.xlsx","companys.xlsx")
data = {'user_name':randStrings.name,'user_email': randStrings.combinedString}
print data
```

my output is : {'user_name': u'duky', 'user_email': u'geri@belleladi.com'}

Need help or advice for two things :

1.Does anyone have a idea or can explain on why there is 'u' character when  getting a record from the excel sheet?? and how to remove this from the output?

2. As you can I've done a extra long .replace() to get rid of any gremlins within the excel . Is there a short or more clean way to do this? like a python reg ex or something. I haven't found any examples dealing with multiple replacements for formating.

Cheers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784148/understanding-repr-function-in-python

Comment: Please consider reading the Python tutorial.

Comment: If you are going to be dealing with Unicode you may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 0):

The u' in front of your records means that they are encode as unicode.

```
>>> a=u'test'
>>> a
u'test'
>>> type(a)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> b="b"
>>> b
'b'
>>> type(b)
<type 'str'>
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

## 1.

The `u` means that the string is Unicode.

## 2.

You can use [string.translate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate)

```
import string
characters_to_remove = " '/.,"
string.translate(random.choice(randCompany).lower(), None, characters_to_remove)
```

Comment: Hey Chris , thanks your example. however i get a error of "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'" ive placed the example first between the random.choice() and second just after where "randCompany" gets set.  But i think string.translate is simliar to REReplace in coldfusion as when i did it in coldfusion all i needed to do REReplace((Lcase(#companyList("companys.xlsx")#)), " |'| ", '', "ALL")> and all formated :D. maybe you can show where i need to put this within the python code?

Comment: Sorry about that, forgot the `random.choice()` part for randCompany. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your encoding is Unicode, which is not the native encoding used by Excel. That is why you get "u" before your strings.

Have you tried the following in Excel : Data -> import your data -> And specifying the encoding (probably utf8) in the import wizard ?

Comment: No i haven't and not sure how to in excel 2013, so does this mean i have to find a way convert the data to a different encoding or something? is there a way to to convert within python instead?

Comment: "Unicode" is not an encoding. Unicode is rendered in specific encodings (such as UTF-8 or UTF-16) on external media.

Comment: @johnny R : It might be easier to do it in Excel. However, if you want to convert it in Python, you might wanna look a the codec module : https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html. 
This is a complex subject, I recommend taking a look at the Unicode doc. For me, this video worked well : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgHbC6udIqc

Answer (score 0):

There is another issue with your code that the other answers do not address.

You are using a rather unusual technique to "return" the data from your function. Although you *do* have a `return` statement, your function call doesn't actually save the returned objects, so your `return` statement is redundant.

You are attaching the data to the function object itself as function attributes `randStrings.name` and `randStrings.combinedString`. Sure, this works, but as I said, it is rather unusual, and it is rare to use function attributes, and when they *are* used it is to do special things, like saving values between function calls.

The normal way to pass data back from a function is like this:

```
def randStrings(excelFile1,excelFile2):
    getNameList = pe.get_sheet(file_name=excelFile1)
    randName = sum([i for i in getNameList],[])
    getCompanyList = pe.get_sheet(file_name=excelFile2)
    randCompany = sum([i for i in getCompanyList],[])
    name = random.choice(randName)
    combinedString = random.choice(randName) + "@" + random.choice(randCompany).lower().replace(" ","").replace("'","").replace("/","").replace(".","").replace(",","") +".com"
    return name, combinedString

name, combinedString = randStrings("names.xlsx","companys.xlsx")
data = {'user_name':name,'user_email': combinedString}
```