# python print escape backslash

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I need python to generate exactly such string literal:

```
e.b=\"e\"
```

But I can't come up with idea how to do so. 
I was trying:

```
r'e.b=\"e\"'      =>     e.b=\\"e\\"
"""e.b=\"e\""""   =>     e.b="e"
```

And many other possibilities but any ends up with exactly **e.b=\"e\"**

Any ideas?

Comment: the first one (`r'e.b=\"e\"'`) should be right. When the python interpreter prints, it will show single `\` characters as `\\`, but if you output it to a file, it should really be just a single `\`.

Comment: Your raw string does what you want. Try printing it with `print`, or writing it to a file. And print its length, which should be 9.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you had it right the first time, except that you examined the [`repr`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7784148/2096752) of the string you created, instead of the string itself:

```
s = r'e.b=\"e\"'
s  # this is the repr() of the string
=> 'e.b=\\"e\\"'
print(repr(s))
=> 'e.b=\\"e\\"'
print(s)  # this is what you want
=> e.b=\"e\"
```

Bottom line, `s=r'e.b=\"e\"'` is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking of printing like this?

```
import re
d = re.escape(r'e.b=\"e\"')
print d
```