# When does Python raise UnicodeDecodeError when searching in string

Tags: python

I have this piece of code that reads from a gunzip stream and checks if each line contains some pattern. What I have is

```
if (pattern in line):
    do_something()
```

Some lines contain non-ASCII characters, when my code reaches those lines, I get a UnicodeDecodeError. However, I am unable to reproduce this error in my manual testing. When I copy the repr of the line that causes UnicodeDecodeError and assign it to variable `line` and do `pattern in line`, I get `False` instead of an error. I am confused about this inconsistency. Why does it behave different for the same string?

Comment: Because `repr(some_string)` is not the same as `some_string`, it is a representation of it. For some types it aspires to give a representation that can be used to construct a new instance of the type if given as input to an interpreter or as code, but not for all. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784148/understanding-repr-function-in-python.

Comment: Aside: if you're a beginner, you should probably be using Python 3 instead of Python 2.  Unicode in particular is handled much better, and while there's still some stuff you have to learn at least what you'll be learning makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I find the root cause of my problem. Somehow, in my actual code `pattern` has type `unicode` instead of `str`, but in manual testing my `pattern` is just a `str` that I type in. This causes the different behaviro I observed.