# Query MongoDB from Python u' get added while retriving data

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-2.7, pymongo

I am trying to retrieve my data from `MongoDB` using `Python` but `u` get added to its key value.

Here is my program:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import json
import array
Data = MongoClient()
Variable = Data.Abhi
Dataset = []
i = 0
Outcome = Variable.Temp.find()

for Result in Outcome:
     Dataset.append(Result)
print Dataset
```

Output :

```
[{u'cuisine': u'Italian', u'borough': u'Manhattan', u'name': u'Vella', u'restaurant_id': u'41704620', u'grades': [{u'grade': u'A', u'score': 11}, {u'grade': u'B', u'score': 17}], u'address': {u'building': u'1480', u'street': u'2 Avenue', u'zipcode': u'10075', u'coord': [-73.9557413, 40.7720266]}, u'_id': ObjectId('576948b163a37b378dc21565')}]
```

I have checked using terminal with find() in my database it is showing

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("576948b163a37b378dc21565"), "cuisine" : "Italian", "name" : "Vella", "restaurant_id" : "41704620", "grades" : [ { "grade" : "A", "score" : 11 }, { "grade" : "B", "score" : 17 } ], "address" : { "building" : "1480", "street" : "2 Avenue", "zipcode" : "10075", "coord" : [ -73.9557413, 40.7720266 ] }, "borough" : "Manhattan" }
```

Please help me where am I making mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Python v2 uses u as prefix to indicate the string is unicode, the literal without the u should make you nervois, as then the content from the db wouöd have öost its encoding. Try print the strings and the u will disappear ;-) in Python v3 there is all unicode or expöicit bytes no more that bytestring.

Comment: As @Dilettant already pointed out, that's the [representation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784148/understanding-repr-function-in-python) for unicode strings. Nothing to fear. By "using terminal with find()" do you mean the mongo shell written in javascript, which is quite different.

Comment: Thanks both of you

Answer (score 0):

you can directly access this by using:

> for Result in Outcome:
>
> Result['your key']

Comment: I think the problem has more to do with the unicode representation. Maybe adding to that explanation will make this answer better. As it stands, you're not explaining why the OP saw the prefix "u" and what that represents.