# decoding to ut8 not working python

Tags: python, encode, python-unicode

I am trying to scrape some data from a website in german. The code is as follows:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2, requests
import time, sys
from selenium import webdriver
import os, sys

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
chromedriver = "./chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
URL = 'http://de.vroniplag.wikia.com/'

def gethtml(link):

    req = urllib2.Request(link, headers={'User-Agent': "Magic Browser"})
    con = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    html = con.read()
    return html


Soup = lambda x: BeautifulSoup(x, 'html.parser')

def getplagtags(url):

    soup = Soup(gethtml(url))
    frgtab = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'ueberpruefte-fragmentseiten'})
    frgs = [e['href'] for e in frgtab.findAll('a') if e['href'] and 'Seite nicht vorhanden' not in e['title']]

    lst=[]
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
    print frgs
    for frg in frgs[0:1]:
        url=URL+frg[1:]
        print url
        driver.get(url)
        for tag in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[class^=fragmark]'):
            lst.append([tag.get_attribute('class'),tag.text.encode('utf-8')])
    driver.quit()
    print lst


getplagtags('http://de.vroniplag.wikia.com/wiki/Aaf')
```

The result is as follows:

```
[[u'fragmark1', 'Verursacher von Infektionen in Krankenh\xc3\xa4usern und'], [u'fragmark2', 'auch in der Bev\xc3\xb6lkerung.'], [u'fragmark3', 'zwei Jahre nach der'], [u'fragmark4', 'des semisynthetischen Penicillin Methicillin,'], [u'fragmark5', 'zur Behandlung von Penicillin-resistentem S. aureus'], [u'fragmark6', 'in einem Krankenhaus in Boston'], [u'fragmark7', 'im Jahr 2006 circa 19.000 Menschen an MRSA-Infektionen.'], [u'fragmark8', 'die Zahl der station\xc3\xa4r behandelten MRSA-Infektionen'], [u'fragmark9', 'zwischen 700 und 1.500 Personen an einer'], [u'fragmark1', 'Die Zahl der Infizierten'], [u'fragmark2', 'Mortalit\xc3\xa4t der Patienten durch schwerwiegende Erkrankungen wie'], [u'fragmark3', 'oder Staphylococcal Scaled Skin Syndrome.'], [u'fragmark4', 'Kosten f\xc3\xbcr das Gesundheitssystem.'], [u'fragmark5', 'in der gegenw\xc3\xa4rtigen Forschung'], [u'fragmark6', 'sind.'], [u'fragmark6', '1.1. Methicillin-resistenter'], [u'fragmark7', 'durch Resistenzen gegen\xc3\xbcber allen Betalaktamantibiotika'], [u'fragmark8', 'als minimale Oxacillin-Hemmkonzentration von \xe2\x89\xa5 4 \xce\xbcg/mL.'], [u'fragmark9', 'einem mobilen genetischen Element.'], [u'fragmark1', 'Durch den Repressor MecI und den Tranducer MecRi'], [u'fragmark2', 'bekannt. Das mecA-Gen kodiert f\xc3\xbcr ein'], [u'fragmark7', 'Jevons MP, Coe AW, Parker MT. Methicillin resistance in staphylococci. Lancet 1963; 1:904-907'], [u'fragmark3', 'Barber M. Methicillin resistant staphylococci. J Clin Path'], [u'fragmark4', 'Barrett FF, McGehee RF Jr, Finland M. Methicillin-resistant Staphylococcus aureus at Boston City Hospital. Bacteriologic and epidemiologic observations. N Engl J Med 1968; 279;441-448'], [u'fragmark1', 'Klevens et al.: Invasive Methicillin-Resistant Staphylococcus aureus Infections in the United States. JAMA 298/15/2007. S. 1763'], [u'fragmark8', 'Klein E, Smith DL, Laxmiranayan R. Hospitalizations and deaths caused by Methicillin-resistant Staphylococcus aureus, United States, 1999'], [u'fragmark9', 'Infect Dis 2007; 13(12):1840-1846'], [u'fragmark2', 'Noskin GA, Rubin RJ,'], [u'fragmark3', 'et al. The burden of Staphylococcus'], [u'fragmark4', 'on hospitals in the United States: an analysis of the 2000 and 2001 Nationwide'], [u'fragmark5', 'Sample Database. Arch Intern Med 2005; 165:1756-1761'], [u'fragmark5', 'Deurenberg RH, Stobberingh EE. The evolution of Staphylococcus aureus. Infect'], [u'fragmark6', 'Evol. 2008 Jul 29.'], [u'fragmark1', 'Verursacher von Infektionen in Krankenh\xc3\xa4usern und'], [u'fragmark2', 'auch in der Bev\xc3\xb6lkerung.'], [u'fragmark3', 'zwei Jahre nach der'], [u'fragmark4', 'des semisynthetischen Penicillin Methicillin'], [u'fragmark5', 'zur Behandlung von Penicillin-resistentem S. aureus'], [u'fragmark6', 'in einem Krankenhaus in Boston'], [u'fragmark7', 'im Jahr 2006 circa 19.000 Menschen an MRSA-Infektionen'], [u'fragmark8', 'die Zahl der station\xc3\xa4r behandelten MRSA-Infektionen'], [u'fragmark9', 'zwischen 700 und 1.500 Personen an einer'], [u'fragmark1', 'die Zahl der Infizierten'], [u'fragmark2', 'Mortalit\xc3\xa4t der Patienten durch schwerwiegende Erkrankungen wie'], [u'fragmark3', 'oder Staphylococcal Scaled Skin Syndrome'], [u'fragmark4', 'Kosten f\xc3\xbcr das Gesundheitssystem,'], [u'fragmark5', 'in der gegenw\xc3\xa4rtigen Forschung'], [u'fragmark6', 'sind.'], [u'fragmark6', '1.1 Methicillin-resistenter'], [u'fragmark7', 'durch Resistenzen gegen\xc3\xbcber allen Betalaktamantibiotika'], [u'fragmark8', 'als minimale Oxacillin-Hemmkonzentration von \xe2\x89\xa5 4 \xce\xbcg/mL.'], [u'fragmark9', 'einem mobilen genetischen Element,'], [u'fragmark1', 'durch den Repressor MecI und den Tranducer MecRi'], [u'fragmark2', 'bekannt. Das mecA-Gen kodiert f\xc3\xbcr ein'], [u'fragmark3', 'Barber M. Methicillin resistant staphylococci. J Clin Path'], [u'fragmark4', 'Barrett FF, McGehee RF Jr, Finland M. Methicillin-resistant Staphylococcus aureus at Boston City Hospital. Bacteriologic and epidemiologic observations. N Engl J Med 1968; 279;441-448'], [u'fragmark5', 'Deurenberg RH, Stobberingh EE. The evolution of Staphylococcus aureus. Infect'], [u'fragmark6', 'Evol. 2008 Jul 29'], [u'fragmark7', 'Jevons MP, Coe AW, Parker MT. Methicillin resistance in staphylococci. Lancet 1963; 1:904-907'], [u'fragmark8', 'Klein E, Smith DL, Laxmiranayan R. Hospitalizations and deaths caused by Methicillin-resistant Staphylococcus aureus, United States, 1999'], [u'fragmark9', 'Infect Dis 2007; 13(12):1840-1846'], [u'fragmark1', 'Klevens et al.: Invasive Methicillin-Resistant Staphylococcus aureus Infections in the United States. JAMA 298/15/2007. S. 1763'], [u'fragmark2', 'Noskin GA, Rubin RJ,'], [u'fragmark3', 'et al. The burden of Staphylococcus'], [u'fragmark4', 'on hospitals in the United States: an analysis of the 2000 and 2001 Nationwide'], [u'fragmark5', 'Sample Database. Arch Intern Med 2005; 165:1756- 1761']]
```

My question is why is the text in the result (the second element in each list) is not in unicode, despite the fact that I am using the encode function.

**UPDATE**:
Removed the setdefaultencoding and the encode function. Now I get the following result

```
[[u'fragmark1', u'Verursacher von Infektionen in Krankenh\xe4usern und'], [u'fragmark2', u'auch in der Bev\xf6lkerung.'], [u'fragmark3', u'zwei Jahre nach der'], [u'fragmark4', u'des semisynthetischen Penicillin Methicillin,'], [u'fragmark5', u'zur Behandlung von Penicillin-resistentem S. aureus'], [u'fragmark6', u'in einem Krankenhaus in Boston'], [u'fragmark7', u'im Jahr 2006 circa 19.000 Menschen an MRSA-Infektionen.'], [u'fragmark8', u'die Zahl der station\xe4r behandelten MRSA-Infektionen'], [u'fragmark9', u'zwischen 700 und 1.500 Personen an einer'], [u'fragmark1', u'Die Zahl der Infizierten'], [u'fragmark2', u'Mortalit\xe4t der Patienten durch schwerwiegende Erkrankungen wie'], [u'fragmark3', u'oder Staphylococcal Scaled Skin Syndrome.'], [u'fragmark4', u'Kosten f\xfcr das Gesundheitssystem.'], [u'fragmark5', u'in der gegenw\xe4rtigen Forschung'], [u'fragmark6', u'sind.'], [u'fragmark6', u'1.1. Methicillin-resistenter'], [u'fragmark7', u'durch Resistenzen gegen\xfcber allen Betalaktamantibiotika'], [u'fragmark8', u'als minimale Oxacillin-Hemmkonzentration von \u2265 4 \u03bcg/mL.'], [u'fragmark9', u'einem mobilen genetischen Element.'], [u'fragmark1', u'Durch den Repressor MecI und den Tranducer MecRi'], [u'fragmark2', u'bekannt. Das mecA-Gen kodiert f\xfcr ein'], [u'fragmark7', u'Jevons MP, Coe AW, Parker MT. Methicillin resistance in staphylococci. Lancet 1963; 1:904-907'], [u'fragmark3', u'Barber M. Methicillin resistant staphylococci. J Clin Path'], [u'fragmark4', u'Barrett FF, McGehee RF Jr, Finland M. Methicillin-resistant Staphylococcus aureus at Boston City Hospital. Bacteriologic and epidemiologic observations. N Engl J Med 1968; 279;441-448'], [u'fragmark1', u'Klevens et al.: Invasive Methicillin-Resistant Staphylococcus aureus Infections in the United States. JAMA 298/15/2007. S. 1763'], [u'fragmark8', u'Klein E, Smith DL, Laxmiranayan R. Hospitalizations and deaths caused by Methicillin-resistant Staphylococcus aureus, United States, 1999'], [u'fragmark9', u'Infect Dis 2007; 13(12):1840-1846'], [u'fragmark2', u'Noskin GA, Rubin RJ,'], [u'fragmark3', u'et al. The burden of Staphylococcus'], [u'fragmark4', u'on hospitals in the United States: an analysis of the 2000 and 2001 Nationwide'], [u'fragmark5', u'Sample Database. Arch Intern Med 2005; 165:1756-1761'], [u'fragmark5', u'Deurenberg RH, Stobberingh EE. The evolution of Staphylococcus aureus. Infect'], [u'fragmark6', u'Evol. 2008 Jul 29.'], [u'fragmark1', u'Verursacher von Infektionen in Krankenh\xe4usern und'], [u'fragmark2', u'auch in der Bev\xf6lkerung.'], [u'fragmark3', u'zwei Jahre nach der'], [u'fragmark4', u'des semisynthetischen Penicillin Methicillin'], [u'fragmark5', u'zur Behandlung von Penicillin-resistentem S. aureus'], [u'fragmark6', u'in einem Krankenhaus in Boston'], [u'fragmark7', u'im Jahr 2006 circa 19.000 Menschen an MRSA-Infektionen'], [u'fragmark8', u'die Zahl der station\xe4r behandelten MRSA-Infektionen'], [u'fragmark9', u'zwischen 700 und 1.500 Personen an einer'], [u'fragmark1', u'die Zahl der Infizierten'], [u'fragmark2', u'Mortalit\xe4t der Patienten durch schwerwiegende Erkrankungen wie'], [u'fragmark3', u'oder Staphylococcal Scaled Skin Syndrome'], [u'fragmark4', u'Kosten f\xfcr das Gesundheitssystem,'], [u'fragmark5', u'in der gegenw\xe4rtigen Forschung'], [u'fragmark6', u'sind.'], [u'fragmark6', u'1.1 Methicillin-resistenter'], [u'fragmark7', u'durch Resistenzen gegen\xfcber allen Betalaktamantibiotika'], [u'fragmark8', u'als minimale Oxacillin-Hemmkonzentration von \u2265 4 \u03bcg/mL.'], [u'fragmark9', u'einem mobilen genetischen Element,'], [u'fragmark1', u'durch den Repressor MecI und den Tranducer MecRi'], [u'fragmark2', u'bekannt. Das mecA-Gen kodiert f\xfcr ein'], [u'fragmark3', u'Barber M. Methicillin resistant staphylococci. J Clin Path'], [u'fragmark4', u'Barrett FF, McGehee RF Jr, Finland M. Methicillin-resistant Staphylococcus aureus at Boston City Hospital. Bacteriologic and epidemiologic observations. N Engl J Med 1968; 279;441-448'], [u'fragmark5', u'Deurenberg RH, Stobberingh EE. The evolution of Staphylococcus aureus. Infect'], [u'fragmark6', u'Evol. 2008 Jul 29'], [u'fragmark7', u'Jevons MP, Coe AW, Parker MT. Methicillin resistance in staphylococci. Lancet 1963; 1:904-907'], [u'fragmark8', u'Klein E, Smith DL, Laxmiranayan R. Hospitalizations and deaths caused by Methicillin-resistant Staphylococcus aureus, United States, 1999'], [u'fragmark9', u'Infect Dis 2007; 13(12):1840-1846'], [u'fragmark1', u'Klevens et al.: Invasive Methicillin-Resistant Staphylococcus aureus Infections in the United States. JAMA 298/15/2007. S. 1763'], [u'fragmark2', u'Noskin GA, Rubin RJ,'], [u'fragmark3', u'et al. The burden of Staphylococcus'], [u'fragmark4', u'on hospitals in the United States: an analysis of the 2000 and 2001 Nationwide'], [u'fragmark5', u'Sample Database. Arch Intern Med 2005; 165:1756- 1761']]
```

Comment: It's not unicode **because** you encoded it.

Comment: You successfully encoded to UTF-8, which is why that second element in each sublist does **not** start with a `u` and contains `\xhh` representations  of bytes that fall outside of the ASCII range. `\xc3\xa4` is the *representation* for the C3 A4 bytes that are the UTF-8 encoding for the U+00E4 `ä` codepoint.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So how can I convert those characters?

Comment: @EchchamaNayak: what output did you *expect*? There is nothing to convert if you expected to have UTF-8 encoded data in your lists. You may have misunderstood how Python shows you what you have in your lists, but the actual contents are still correctly encoded UTF-8 bytestrings.

Comment: @MartijnPieters As you said the \xa4 is ä. So how do I get that in the final output. Because I need to perform an operation with this text.

Comment: @EchchamaNayak: No, `\xa4` is **one** byte in a two-byte UTF-8 encoding for `ä`. Why are you encoding to UTF-8 in the first place?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry if I am not clear. My intention is to extract the German text as it is published on the website. Yet I get these obfuscations. How do I get the ä and not \x characters

Comment: @EchchamaNayak: you are printing a list object. The representation of any standard Python container is to use `repr()` on each element, and you are looking at that representation. If you must further manipulate the text, **don't encode**, keep the text as Unicode. Don't print the list objects, print individual values. You have the right data, you are just getting confused over the (debug) output you see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You decode from str to unicode and encode from unicode to str. `tag.text.encode('utf-8')` obviously gives you exactly what you asked for, just call `tag.text` as you already have a unicode string:

```
 [tag.get_attribute('class'),tag.text]
```

Also avoid `reload(sys)`  and `sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')`, [why-should-we-not-use-sys-setdefaultencodingutf-8-in-a-py-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828723/why-should-we-not-use-sys-setdefaultencodingutf-8-in-a-py-script)

Comment: Hi! As you say the characters are now unicode. But some characters have't converted, what do I do?

Comment: @EchchamaNayak, have not converted to what exactly? Are you talking about things like `gegen\xfcber`? i.e the repr representation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784148/understanding-repr-function-in-python

Comment: Yes that is what I meant

Comment: That is just the repr representation, when you actually print the strings you will see what you expect. `print(u"station\xe4r") -> stationär`