# Unreasonable output from codecs.decode()

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding

I have been playing around with the `codecs` module lately and I stumbled upon this behavior that I find rather weird:
`codecs.encode(b'a', 'hex')` returns `b'61'`.

My question is, why? I really didn't expect it to return `b'61'`. I was expecting `b'\x61'`.
The former is a `bytes` object with length 2 (`len(b'61') == 2`), whereas the latter one is a `bytes` object with length 1 (`len(b'\x61') == 1`).

I didn't expect this behavior at all, because `b'a'`, which is supposed to be 1-byte, has became 2-bytes when encoded with the `'hex'` codecs.

What would you have done to convert an ASCII character to its hex-encoded `bytes` representation? What I did was:

```
codecs.decode(hex(ord('a'))[2:], 'hex')
```

But I felt like this is kind of a dirty hack.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#binary-transforms, "Convert operand to hexadecimal representation, with two digits per byte"

Comment: Also as you yourself point out, `b'\x61'` is just another way of saying `b'a'`. They are **the same byte string** written in different **representation**. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784148/understanding-repr-function-in-python.

Comment: My bad. Thanks for pointing out the RTFM advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour of codec is documented, the purpose is to make a text representation of (possibly) binary data.

If you want to convert a character 'a' to a bytes representation of that character using ascii, you don't need the codec module; just use the `bytes` builtin.

```
>>> bytes('a','ascii')
b'a'
```

As noted in the comments, b'a' is equal to b'\x61'