# Unwanted quotations marks in python terminal

Tags: python

I am using Geany to code and Ubuntu 16.04 as my OS.
when I enter this code

```
print("Result:",a+b)
```

It gives it's output as `('Result:', a+b)`.

Comment: Where does this happen? Are you running your script from within geany, or the cli ?

Comment: `print "Result:",a+b` It will work in python 2.7.6

Comment: how about this: `print("{!s}{}".format('Result:', a+b))`

Comment: You're apparently using python2, in which "print" is a statement instead of a function. In your case the statement prints the [representation of the 2-tuple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784148/understanding-repr-function-in-python) `("Result", a+b)`. Concider using python3.

Comment: Or `from __future__ import print_function` to use the `print` function in Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

In **python 2**:

```
print("Result:",a+b) --> # ('Result:', 6)
```

parens are no needed, because otherwise we are printing a tuple of two elements: string `'Result'` and an integer `6`.

In **python 3**:

```
print("Result:",a+b) --> # Result: 6
```

parens are needed, just because print is a function instead of a statement in python 3.

So to do it the same in python 2 which is in python 3, you have to do this:

```
print "Result:", a+b --> # Result: 6
```

Comment: Not "just" because of syntax in python 3, but because print is a function instead of a statement. The difference is much deeper than just syntax.

Comment: Sorry for not being concrete. Edited.