# Appending multiple strings together and printing them throws up '/' character where double quotation marks exist

Tags: string, python-3.x, subprocess

I am running a Java tool called snpSift and would like to run it on multiple files. As such I am using a pythong script and using subprocess. The actual command I am trying to create a string of is:

```
java -jar SnpSift.jar filter "ANN[0].EFFECT has 'variant'" input.vcf > ~/output.vcf
```

This command is correct as I have used it directly on the command line myself. I have created a list called variantType which contains strings of different variants that I intend to use as a variable when running snpSift.

I am trying to create another list (command) that will contain the entire command line input as a string for each file and each variantType. My script is below:

```
command = [] 
for file in os.listdir("filepath"):  
    absfile = os.path.abspath(file)  
    if(file.endswith(".vcf")):
        for i in variantType:  
            w = 'java -jar SnpSift.jar filter "'
            x = "ANN[0].EFFECT has "  
            y = "'" + i + "'"
            z = '" ' + absfile +  " > output." + i + "." + str(file)
            command.append(w+x+y+z)
```

My issue is that the input for the filter has to have quotation marks in this manner: `"ANN[0].EFFECT has 'variant'"`

My attempts to do this using double quotation marks have failed, and result in the following output:

```
'java -jar SnpSift.jar filter "ANN[0].EFFECT has \'transcript_ablation\'" input.vcf > ~output.vcf'
```

How can I remove those '\' characters? If I print y (the variable containing that part of the entire string) these characters are not printed, but when I print the entire command, they are there, and therefore I cannot run the command properly.

EDIT

When I use:

```
print(command[0])
```

This prints the desired command (without the '\').

It is only when I use:

```
command[0]
```

That the issue occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I am not yet allowed to comment, however, maybe this answer still helps you.

You can check which character there is at a specific position in your string by accessing that character directly (`somestr[position]`). I ran you code example (slightly modified, e.g. using format to create the command) and tested which character there is at position 48 and it turns out that it is indeed a single quote with ASCII code 39:

```
import os

variantType = ['variant', 'test']

command = []

absfile = "/tmp.vcf"
file = "tmp.vcp"

for i in variantType:
    w = 'java -jar SnpSift.jar filter "ANN[0].EFFECT has \'{v}\'" input.vcf > ~/output.vcf'.format(v=i)

    command.append(w)

print(", ".join([str(x) for x in command]))

for x in command:
    print(repr(x))
    print(str(x))
    print(ord(x[48]))
```

The output then is as follows:

```
['java -jar SnpSift.jar filter "ANN[0].EFFECT has \'variant\'" input.vcf > ~/output.vcf', 'java -jar SnpSift.jar filter "ANN[0].EFFECT has \'test\'" input.vcf > ~/output.vcf']
java -jar SnpSift.jar filter "ANN[0].EFFECT has 'variant'" input.vcf > ~/output.vcf, java -jar SnpSift.jar filter "ANN[0].EFFECT has 'test'" input.vcf > ~/output.vcf
'java -jar SnpSift.jar filter "ANN[0].EFFECT has \'variant\'" input.vcf > ~/output.vcf'
java -jar SnpSift.jar filter "ANN[0].EFFECT has 'variant'" input.vcf > ~/output.vcf
'
39
'java -jar SnpSift.jar filter "ANN[0].EFFECT has \'test\'" input.vcf > ~/output.vcf'
java -jar SnpSift.jar filter "ANN[0].EFFECT has 'test'" input.vcf > ~/output.vcf
'
39
```

As you can see, for each command, the first print statement creates the "malformed" string representation (using the object's `__repr__` function), and the second version produces the nicely formated one (using the object's `__str__` function).

What is happening when you call `print(somelist)` is that python prints the `repr` value of each object in `somelist`, which could enable you to recreate your list from the printed list string using the `eval` function.

Check the following links for more information on the difference between `__repr__()` and `__str()__`:

- [Understanding repr( ) function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784148/understanding-repr-function-in-python)
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Whilst what you recommend works when printing a statement, when I wish to run the subprocess by using: 'for i in command:
    subprocess.call(i)' the same issue with the / occurs.

Comment: You can try to alter my example by replacing `w = '/bin/echo "\'{v}\'"'.format(v=i)`. Then try to launch this command in the for loop `print(subprocess.call(x, shell=True))` (that shell=True is important, as otherwise subprocess will interpret the _x_ differently. What I get as output from this call to _echo_ then is `'test'`. Does that work for you? What's the error message in detail?