# Flask SQLAlchemy - Access record data without column name

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Long time reader, first time asker.  I'm a little unsure of how to express what I am trying to accomplish.  Using `Flask` and `SQLAlchemy`, I am attempting to put data from a record (in this case, system.xxx) into a table. When I use `system.xxx`, I also get the column name, as pictured below:

[what I don't want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJzBO.png)

This is the code I'm using in my jinja template:

```
{% block page_content %}
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>{{ system.serial }}</h1>
</div>
<hr width="80%">
<table class="table", border="5">
    <tr>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Assignee</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ system.status }}</td>
        <td>{{ system.assignee }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

How can I access `system.xxx` without getting the '`Status u`' or '`Assignee u`' column info? I've spent literally hours on the inter webs trying to figure this out, but I don't know how to properly phrase the question.

Added: the flask view.

```
@main.route('/system/<serial>', methods=['GET'])
def system(serial):
    system = System.query.filter_by(serial=serial).first_or_404()
    return render_template('system.html', system=system)
```

Added: the models in question

```
#table of individual systems
class System(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'systems'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    serial = db.Column(db.String(64))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    status_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('statuses.id'))
    assignee_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('assignees.id'))
    admin = db.Column(db.String)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<System %r>' % self.serial

#table of assignees
class Assignee(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'assignees'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    systems = db.relationship('System', backref='assignee', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Assignee %r>' % self.name

#table of status options
class Status(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'statuses'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    systems = db.relationship('System', backref='status', lazy='dynamic')

    @staticmethod
    def insert_statuses():
        statuses = ['Available', 'Loaned', 'Scrapped']
        for status in statuses:
            s = Status(name=status)
            db.session.add(s)
        db.session.commit()

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Status %r>' % self.name
```

Comment: Can you share the flask view that generate this template please ?

Comment: I have added the view to the post , thanks.

Comment: Are `status` and `assignee` actually relationship properties? Please include your model. In other words produce a [mcve]. Prolly

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've updated the post with the models in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I thought you're accessing the related  `Status` and `Assignee` objects through a [relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationships.html) property in your template, which then renders them using their [string representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784148/understanding-repr-function-in-python). Instead you should access the attributes you want to display:

```
        <td>{{ system.status.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ system.assignee.name }} {{ system.assignee.email }}</td>
```

Since you'll always be accessing those relationships you should consider eagerloading them.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks for the help! I'll look into eagerloading.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly query for *only* the columns you want.

```py
first_result = session.query(System.xxx).filter(System.serial == serial).scalar()
```

You may also wish to use `one_or_none()`, `one()` or `all()` depending on your use case.

Comment: I am able to get the information I'm looking for (    system.status), but it also includes the column name, so it shows up as <Status u'Loaned'>, instead of simply Loaned.

Comment: I'm guessing `System.status` is of `Enum` type. If you wish to get the string representation of `status`, you'll have to use `str(system.status)` or `system.status.value` or whatever your actual Enum type implementation offers.