# How to get access to relationship field?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have follow model of my DB:

```
class User(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'users'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = Column(String)
  adr = relationship('Address', backref='uuu')

class Address(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'addresses'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  email = Column(String, nullable=False)
  # user_id = Column(Integer)
  user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

answer = sess.query(User).first()
print(answer.adr)
```

It's print:
`[<__main__.Address object at 0x7fed81592e50>]`

But by the [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/backref.html) it should print value instead address.

> The above configuration establishes a collection of `Address` objects on `User` called `User.addresses`. It also establishes a `.user` attribute on `Address` which will refer to the parent `User` object.

I tried follow code:

```
answer = sess.query(User).first()
print(answer.adr.email)
```

Error:

`AttributeError: 'InstrumentedList' object has no attribute 'email'`

Comment: This is a good time to read ["Understanding `repr()` function in Python"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784148/understanding-repr-function-in-python). Long story short: `<Address object at 0x7fe...>` is the string representation of an `Address` object. In other words you're seeing exactly what you should be seeing, given `print(answer.adr)`. If you want to see emails of individual addresses, loop over the address objects.

Comment: If your relationship type is one-to-one change the statement to 
`adr = relationship('Address', uselist=False, backref='uuu')`, Otherwise it will return a list which you need to iterate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it prints is absolutely correct.

If you want values of individual columns, you need to print for example `answer.adr.email`. And note that `answer.adr` is a list, not an object, so you need to iterate through it as well.

Comment: Note that `answer.adr` is a collection, not a single address object.

Comment: @IljaEverilä but why it's return collection, but not single object?

Comment: Because your model as it is is many to one. There can be many Address records with user_id pointing to a single User record. When you reference addresses from a user record, there can be none, one or many addresses as a result. If you know there will be only one, you can do what Ilja suggested in comments to your question - but then you must make sure it is one to one, otherwise you will end up with run time exceptions.