# Convert listdir() return to byte for decoding

Tags: python, encoding, listdir

I have a list of dir with name encoded in 'gbk', for example:

```
dirs
  |- b'\xb6\xb0'/
  |- b'\xc1\xb1'/
  |- b'\xc9\xdd'/
```

However, when I use `os.listdir()` is return a list of str, like below:

```
["b'\\xb6\\xb0'", "b'\\xc1\\xb1'", "b'\\xc9\\xdd'"]
```

How can I cast the string to byte and decode it to get the original characters? I tried `str.encode.decode` but still not working.

Thanks.

Comment: Are your directories actually named like `b'\xb6\xb0'`? As in if you check the directory in a console or such, you see the same listing.

Comment: It's something like `b'\xc1\xf2'/` in the terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've used the [string representation of `bytes` objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784148/understanding-repr-function-in-python) as the name of your directories, instead of creating directories using the encoded byte string as the name. To undo the plunder you could in this particular case use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to evaluate the string representation and then decode the resulting `bytes` object:

```
import os
import ast

dirs = [ast.literal_eval(d).decode('gbk') for d in os.listdir(...)]
```

Please note that `ast.literal_eval()` is used here only to recover the directory names and you should recreate them properly; in other words they should not have been created this way to begin with.