# Converting a Python datetime object that is in utc to local time

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, localization

I want to show expiry dates for SSL certificates to the user. These expiry dates are in UTC, so when the expiry date is today at noon, it will show `12/08/2020 12:00:00`. However, since I am in the Berlin timezone, that means the certificate will actually expire at 14:00:00 localtime, which is what I want to show to the user. I tried the following:

```
end_date = certificate_end_date.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).astimezone(tz=None)
```

But since the certificate is valid until 2045, this produces the following error message:

```
OverflowError: timestamp out of range for platform time_t
```

I searched and people suggested just using a timedelta, but that is complicated again due to daylight savings time. There has to be a proper way to do this? I am using Python3.7.

Comment: what is `certificate_end_date`? a datetime object? what is its `repr`?

Comment: Yes, it's a datetime object. I don't understand exactly what you mean by what its `repr` is. If I print it, it's just the datetime without any timezone information: `>>> certificate_end_date
datetime.datetime(2045, 1, 1, 12, 0)
>>> print(certificate_end_date)
2045-01-01 12:00:00
`

Comment: by `repr` I mean [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784148/understanding-repr-function-in-python) - the first part of what you posted in the comment ;-) I think your line of code is perfectly fine, however I'm confused that it throws this error. On my system, `datetime(2045, 1, 1, 12, 0).replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).astimezone()` works fine... (Python 3.8.5 x64 on Windows 10).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by calculating the timedelta as recommended elsewhere, although it still looks kind of ugly to me:

```
 from datetime import datetime, timezone

 now = datetime.now()
 offset = now.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc) - now.astimezone(timezone.utc)

 localtime = utc_time + offset
```

Comment: are you looking for your local time's UTC offset? you can obtain that via `datetime.now().astimezone().utcoffset()`

Comment: Yes this is basically what I was looking for, however I thought there was a way to tell python that this datetime object is in UTC and that I want it to be shown in localtime (i.e. not adding the offset manually before returning it to the user).

Comment: ok you could create an aware datetime object then as `dt = datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)`. if you want to show (print) its local time representation, use `print(dt.astimezone())`. the thing with Python is that it treats naive datetime objects as local time while in many other languages, it's UTC. Kind of a pitfall. I suggest to define the time zone whenever you can.