# SQL Alchemy not returning all the columns

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy

When I query my sqlalchemy database it does not display all the columns but only one
for example

```
User.query.all()
```

returns

```
User('Andrew')
```

but it should return

```
User('Andrew','Andrew677@gmail.com')
```

Below is my model

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(10), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(15), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
```

I believe I have configured sqlalchemy correctly because it does store users when I create them but does not allow me to query also when I use

```
User.query.count()
```

it returns the correct amount of users in the table but it does not return all the columns, this is happening in all my tables

Comment: A loop like this should work: 
`users = User.query.all()
for user in users:
    print(user.username)`

Comment: You should read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784148/understanding-repr-function-in-python. What you see is just the representation of a `User`. You should explicitly access the attributes to produce any desired output format.