# Why does my sqlite query not print all data?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've noticed that my query is getting all data from my joined tables but I can only read that data when I specifically try and access it.

My unedited file:

```
query = db.session.query(Rating, Song).filter(Rating.id==Song.id).all()
print(query) #<----- This prints [(4.75, MMMBop), (3.00, bombastic)]
for x in query:
    print(f"{x[1].title}:{x[1].artist}:{x[1].released}") #<-- This prints MMMBop:Hansons:1997\nbombastic:shaggy:1995
```

Why is this?

EDIT

I have added my model now. repr was the first thing I checked and I have run the code again after a reboot so there can't be any variables lurking. No repr is even including the artist and release.

```
from application import db

association_table = db.Table('association',
                             db.Column('songs_id', db.Integer,
                                       db.ForeignKey('songs.id')),
                             db.Column('genres_id', db.Integer,
                                       db.ForeignKey('genres.id'))
                             )


class Rating(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'songs_ratings'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    rating = db.Column(db.Numeric(precision=3, scale=2),
                       index=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.rating)


class Song(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'songs'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(80), index=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    artist = db.Column(db.String(30), primary_key=False,
                       unique=False, nullable=False)
    release = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False)
    genres = db.relationship(
        "Genre", secondary=association_table, backref=db.backref('songs'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.title)


class Genre(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'genres'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    category = db.Column(db.String(80), index=True,
                         unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.category)
```

Comment: What library are you using to connect to the database? Will you show your imports?

Comment: I am importing sqlalchemy and using it in my models

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()

Comment: Looks like ["Understanding repr( ) function in Python"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784148/understanding-repr-function-in-python) can help make sense of it.

Comment: @user15821144 Please [edit] your question to include that

Comment: repr is now included

Comment: Completely different question: why is `Rating` a separate table if it is just 1-1 relationship with `Song`? And even if you want to have it separately, why not creating a `1-1` actual `relationship` between the entities?

Comment: That's a good point, I intend to use ratings for machine learning so I thought it would be best to seperate them. I tried 1-1 relationship between songs and rating but was unsuccessful because I find sqlalchemy to be hard. Even after reading all the tutorials I could find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, your query returns all the data (as you can probably see from the issued SQL statements).

The issue is not that you cannot "see" the data, but rather what you see when you use "print" statement.

```
query = db.session.query(Rating, Song).filter(Rating.id==Song.id).all()
print(query) #<----- This prints [(4.75, MMMBop), (3.00, bombastic)]
```

The reason above prints what you see is because both `Rating` and `Song` have `__repr__` method, which prints only `rating` and `title` respectively.

But when you executed the below print statement, you are deciding what to print:

```
for x in query:
    print(f"{x[1].title}:{x[1].artist}:{x[1].released}") #<-- This prints MMMBop:Hansons:1997\nbombastic:shaggy:1995
```

**My suggestion** would be for you to implement a more verbose `Song.__repr__` method to include all the columns you care about.

Answer (score 0):

The output you see from `print(query)` is just a string representation of the `query` object. It does not give you any information about how to access the underlying data. I suggest you read more sqlalchemy tutorials and documentation to find out how to correctly use the results of `db.session.query()`. In this case, you need to fetch all the rows as a cursor:

```
for x in query.fetchall():
```

Comment: `Query` is not a cursor as such, and after having called `Query.all()` like in the question all you have is a `list`, which can be seen from the representation.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Thanks for the clarification. Please edit my answer with the correct wording/terminology. I'm only passingly familiar with sqlalchemy, so corrections are welcome.